# When trying to perform GaussianNB on data get TypeError - python beginner

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, gaussian, naivebayes, sklearn-pandas

i'm trying to build a prediction model using GaussianNB.

I have a csv file that looks like this:
[csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI71h.png)

My code looks like as follows:

```
encoded_df = pd.read_csv('path to file')

y = encoded_df.iloc[:,12]

X = encoded_df.iloc[:,0:12]
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(X, y)

prediction_test_naive = ['427750', '426259', '2', '1610', '2', '1', '2', '1', '4', '1', '47', '2']

naive_predicted_class = model.predict(np.reshape(prediction_test_naive, [1, -1]))

print("predicted Casualty Severity: 1 = slight, 2 = serious, 3 = fatal: ", naive_predicted_class)

expected_bayes = y
predicted_bayes = model.predict(X)

classification_report_bayes = metrics.classification_report(expected_bayes, predicted_bayes)

print(classification_report_bayes)
```

When ran i get the type error:

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching  types dtype('U32') dtype('U32') dtype('U32')

The error appears to be coming from line 7 in the example code above. but other than that i do not know.

i'm not really sure how to fix this, I have a decision tree that works but would like to use bayes theorem too.

Comment: Can you post the sample data as text which is producing this error.

Comment: 418241,442351,2,1905,2,2,2,1,1,1,38,7,2
424993,432898,2,1615,1,2,2,1,1,2,50,1,1
431159,436397,2,1645,1,2,1,1,1,1,26,1,1
431159,436397,2,1645,1,2,1,1,2,2,22,1,1
439313,432376,2,956,2,1,1,1,1,1,57,2,1
426994,439957,2,1115,2,2,1,1,1,1,59,2,2
427813,431257,1,1352,3,1,1,1,1,2,53,1,2
431496,432727,2,2015,1,1,2,3,2,2,22,1,1
431880,430498,2,1110,3,1,1,1,2,2,20,1,1

theres an example of it, the actual data has roughly 2500 entries

Comment: Does this sample data produce the error?

Comment: yeah, i actually have 2 different datasets and they both produce the error. The decision tree function works correctly with the data however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to this line:

```
prediction_test_naive = ['427750', '426259', '2', '1610', '2', '1', '2', '1', '4', '1', '47', '2']
```

Here you are declaring a list of strings (by using a single inverted commas around the values) which is then used to prediction. But in the model, only numerical values are allowed. So you need to convert them to numerical.

For this you can use the following ways:

1) Declare the  `prediction_test_naive` as numbers like this (Notice that inverted commas have been removed):

```
prediction_test_naive = [427750, 426259, 2, 1610, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 47, 2]
```

2) Convert the prediction_test_naive to numerical using numpy

After this line:

```
prediction_test_naive = ['427750', '426259', '2', '1610', '2', '1', '2', '1', '4', '1', '47', '2']
```

Do this:

```
prediction_test_naive = np.array(prediction_test_naive, dtype=float)
```